# How do I get the search result using the Lucene search syntax of "*/&querytype=full"?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

We want to create a custom analyzer in Azure Cognitive Search that converts a search consisting of the following query string into two tokens: a 1-byte character and a 2-byte character.

I have tested the following three things

1. Query search with strings only. Both 1-byte and 2-byte characters are displayed with no problems. (OK)
2. Query search using a regular expression of string + "*". There is no problem in displaying both 1-byte and 2-byte characters. (OK)
3. String + "/. *(1-byte character)."*/&querytype=full" query search using Lucene search syntax. Nothing is displayed. (NG)

I don't know why (2) succeed for a query search using a regular expression but not (3).

1. [Query string : 1-byte character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wywMu.png)
   (OK pattern)
2. [Query string : 1-byte character + "*(regular expression)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THgw0.png)
   (OK pattern)
3. [Query string : /.*(※1-byte character).*/&querytype=full](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf5pI.png)
   (**NG pattern**)

[Questions]

1. Can you tell me how to use the query string in above 3 to search for 1-byte and 2-byte characters?
2. Can you tell me if you know why the query string in above 3 doesn't search for 1-byte and 2-byte characters?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your problem, but I'll try to describe my understanding.

Your index has a document that contains the following text:

> シヤ一ブ

Your index has another document that contains

> シャ一プ

The difference between your two documents is that they use either single- or multibyte characters to describe the same text. Your goal is that a query for either シヤ一ブ or シャ一プ should return both documents. This works, except when you enable queryType=full.

My apologies if I got the texts wrong. I had to do OCR on the screenshots you attached. It would help if you pasted the actual example texts here so we can accurately reproduce.

From your linked screenshots I see that the content is stored in a property called F_KEYWORDS. Have you specified a Japanese language analyzer for the property F_KEYWORDS?